# Change Excel web app source on click in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am working with Share Point webapp 2010 and I need to visualize KPIs on my webpage. I am using excel web access, but I need to change excel source when person click on different links. I am very new to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

In this case I used HTML web form to add links in the webpage, than in excel web access part in the dropdown portion click on connections->Html web form, It will show all the name attributes of your HTML web form. Select one which you want to use for you application.